# Why does pd.DataFrame with pd.isnull fail?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
tt = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,None,3],'b':[None,3,4,5]})
bb=pd.DataFrame(pd.isnull(tt).astype(int), index = tt.index, columns=map(lambda x: x + '_'+'NA',tt.columns))
bb
```

[image]

I want create this dataframe with `pd.isnull(tt)`, and the columns name contain the NA, but why does this fail?

Comment: In general you should try the different components and see where the issue happens, in this case `pd.isnull(tt).astype(int)` works as you would expect but the pd.DataFrame constructor is the issue i.e. this question is not about pd.isnull but pd.DataFrame constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `values`

```
tt = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,None,3],'b':[None,3,4,5]})
bb=pd.DataFrame(data=pd.isnull(tt).astype(int).values, index = tt.index, columns=list(map(lambda x: x + '_'+'NA',tt.columns)))
```

***The reason why*** :
 `pandas` data carry over the column and index , which `pd.isnull(tt).astype(int)` already have the columns name as `b` and `a`

More information

```
bb=pd.DataFrame(data=pd.isnull(tt).astype(int), index = tt.index,columns=['a','b', 'a_NA','b_NA'] )
bb
Out[399]: 
   a  b  a_NA  b_NA
0  0  1   NaN   NaN
1  0  0   NaN   NaN
2  1  0   NaN   NaN
3  0  0   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: I cannot think of a case where pd.DataFrame(df, ...) would ever be best idea.

Comment: @AndyHayden me either... But it just happened during op's work :-)